# remove rows from JTable with AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I would like to remove selected row from `JTable` with `AbstractTableModel` using a button.

The code below works with DefaultTableModel:

```
...
MyTableModel mtb;
...
private String[]....
private Object[][]...
...
JTable table = new JTable(mtb)
JButton delete;
...
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource().equals(delete))
         {
                 if(table.getSelectedRow()<0)
                 {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Select row");

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     mtb.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow()); 

                 }
         }
     }
```

but it deosn't work with `AbstractTablemodel`.

I have a little mess in my code so here is [java example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDemoProject/src/components/TableDemo.java) from oracle page that can be used:

Thanks!

Comment: It does not work since that method is not defined. Just add such a method to your `TableModel` and make sure that method fires the proper events. Note that the code in your question is rather irrelevant for proposing a solution. We would need your `TableModel` iso an `actionPerformed` method to give useful advise

Comment: OK, I thought that there is a similar defined method as it is in DefaultTableModel but now I know I need to define it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For `AbstractTableModel`, you have to implement your own `removeRow()` based on your model's internal data structure(s), but you can study the source of `DefaultTableModel` as a guide on which event(s) to fire. For example,

```
public void removeRow(int row) {
    // remove a row from your internal data structure
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

Comment: I've found more relevant tip: "It's not easy to add data to an existing array, you have to create a new array bigger than the old one, copy all the data across, and then add the new item. Far better to use a Vector or an ArrayList."

Comment: *I've found more relevant tip* our magic crystal ball probably failed to reveal you were using an array as internal data structure. +1 for this answer which is about the best one could do with the available info in the question

Comment: Although not deprecated, `Vector` is a legacy class. Consider coding to the interface, e.g. `List<Row>`, which lets you change implementations as required

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultTableModel` will itself call `fireXX` methods whenever there is a change in the table model. But if we use `AbstractTableModel` then we have to explicitly call `fireXX` methods. So when ever there is a change in the table just call relevant `fireXX` method.

For,

**inserting** a new row to the table use [fireTableRowsInserted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29)

**deletion** (in your case) use  [fireTableRowsDeleted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)

**update** use [fireTableRowsUpdated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsUpdated%28int,%20int%29)

**NOTE:** `DefaultTableModel` has most of all the methods implemented. So unless there is a real need go for `AbstractTableModel` else stick with `DefaultTableModel`.