# How to clear selection from JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I've created a Java application where there's a `JTable` containing data and a button to update database from the table. Is there anyway to clear the selection (row and column) from this `JTable`? I've tried `JTable#clearSelection()`, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The [`clearSelection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#clearSelection--) method "Deselects all selected columns and rows." It only removes the selection highlighting, not the data. To actually clear the cell, you'll have to remove the cell's data from the `TableModel`, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13880668/230513).

```
public void clearCell(int row, int col) {
    // remove the data from your internal data structure
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```